# VBA does not select range although apparent select statement

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm creating automated pivottables from a pivotcache which imports its recordset form an adodb connection.

I need to group the date field and found a way online to do it with the .pivotselect method. The code works fine, however excel does not seem to select the worksheet where the pivottables are somehow, even though the pivottable data is selected. This leads to an error if one select another sheet and then runs the procedure.

Shouldn't pivottable.pivotselect select the sheet also automatically? I have solved it temporarily by having sheets("Pivot").select just before the date grouping code. How may one come around this problem? The current code is based on code generated from macro recorder.

Code

```
Private Sub PivotAccessADODB()
' Link Pivottable to access database, successfull!

Const ConnectionPath As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\name\Desktop\DataBase.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"


    Dim DataConnection As ADODB.Connection: Set DataConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet: Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet

    DataConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionPath
    DataConnection.Open

    Dim SQLString As String: SQLString = "SELECT * FROM ALFA"

    With RecordSet
        .ActiveConnection = DataConnection
        .Source = SQLString
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
    End With

' Initiate accept of external data
Dim PTCache As PivotCache

Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlExternal)
Set PTCache.RecordSet = RecordSet

'----------------------------------'
'First Pivot Table export procedure
Dim PT As PivotTable: Set PT = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(Sheets("Pivot").Range("A1"), "PivotTable#1")

With PT
    .PivotFields("Date").Orientation = xlRowField
    .PivotFields("Date").Position = 1

    Sheets("pivot").Select ' Bypass selection grouping error, temporary solution as of 2014-12-26
    PT.PivotSelect "Date[All]", xlLabelOnly + xlFirstRow, True
    Selection.Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, False, True, False, False)

    .PivotFields("Adj Close").Orientation = xlDataField
        .PivotFields("Sum of Adj Close").Calculation = xlPercentDifferenceFrom
        .PivotFields("Sum of Adj Close").BaseItem = "(previous)"

    .PivotFields("Volume").Orientation = xlDataField
        .PivotFields("Sum of Volume").Calculation = xlPercentDifferenceFrom
        .PivotFields("Sum of Volume").BaseItem = "(previous)"
End With

    Dim wst As Worksheet: Set wst = Sheets("Mainwindow")
    Dim wshape As Shape
    Set wshape = wst.Shapes.AddChart2(286, xl3DColumnClustered, wst.Range("A24").Left, wst.Range("A24").Top, _
    wst.Range("A24:Q24").Width, wst.Range("A24:A39").Height)

With wshape.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=PT.TableRange1
    .ClearToMatchStyle
    .ChartStyle = 291
    .ApplyLayout (1)
    .ChartTitle.Text = "Difference from previous month in percentage"
    .ChartTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Size = 14
End With

'-----------------------------------'
'Second Pivot Table export procedure'



'Cleanup
 RecordSet.Close
 DataConnection.Close
 Set RecordSet = Nothing
 Set DataConnection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging by stepping through the code one line at a time while watching your Locals window?  Is this line the issue 'Sheets("pivot").Select'?

Comment: Just create a Woksheet variable, assign ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot") to it and use that as your WorkSheet reference.

Comment: The "Sheets("Pivot").select is just a temporary solution to prevent the error. I have stepped through the code and the code fails at the second next line to "Sheets("Pivot").select if one does not have that sheet selected at the time running the code.

Comment: I tried your suggestion cool blue but still the same error occurs.

Comment: OK. Why do you need to select the entire worksheet? What happens if you just set a range variable to a single cell in the PT data range and call the Group Method on that? Have you read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839808(v=office.15).aspx)? And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835831(v=office.15).aspx)?

Comment: I have now tried several methods but none have worked, either it's an error with the method itself ( seems that they updated some methods recently ) or it's the same error. What startles me is that the current procedure cannot function without having the pivot sheet active, although VBA clearly selects the datarange for the Date pivotfield ( confirmed by stepping through the code )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to dimension a Worksheet object and set it to the whatever worksheet has the pivot tables:

```
Dim wkb    As Excel.Workheet

Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheet("Me")

wkb.Activate 'wkb.Select may give focus but doesn't register as the active worksheet object.

<PT Code>

Set wkb = Nothing
```